# how to create a simple module to inject application module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to create a module which has a directive with template "Hello world" and inject this module to base module(application) while initialize web page the the directive should compiled and append to `<body>`?

```
angular.module('helloWorld',[]).provider(['helloWorld',function(ngModalView){

    return{
        $get : [function($compile, $scope){
             var tem = $compile('<hello-world></hello-world>')($scope);
             //append this template to body
        }]
    };

}]);

angular.module('helloWorld',[]).directive('helloWorld',[function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',      
            replace: true,
            template: '<div style="width=150px;height="150px">Hello world</div>'  
        };
}]);
```

I need to run above module while application starts.

```
angular.module('app',['helloWorld']);
```

Comment: Give us some more info or snippets

Comment: a sample code attached with question

Comment: You mean lazy loading of modules?

Comment: Is that answer helped you? Or you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever angular app bootstraps, first it will load the dependency modules (in your case "helloWorld") and then the main module "app" would be loaded. So you dont worry about loading/running dependent modules.

If you are thinking about lazy loading of modules, then look at this urls

https://oclazyload.readme.io/